# How long should my cookie token be?

Tags: php, cookies, random, hash, sha256

This is what i've come up with to store a cookie to validate a user on my site.

How long should the token be that I generate? Is 33 enough or should it be 64? and is my generation secure enough?

```
<?PHP 
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(33));
echo $token.'<br>';
$hash = hash('sha256', $token);
echo $hash;

//Test user db and local cookie
    $stored_hash = '5be39777ad41916c5fa1e78681bfc8793a5cfe7c27842846ad23396e44b390a7';
    $cookie = '1a9243f95354252d937d2b99e64a7eeb462e00c72b26d488426f08ef11667522c6';

$cookie_hash = hash('sha256', $cookie);

if(hash_equals($stored_hash, $cookie_hash))
  echo 'true';
else
  echo 'false';
?>
```

Comment: how paranoid do you feel? how many tokens are you going to be storing?

Comment: around 10k users. as far as paranoid just want to be secure. is there a huge security difference from 33 and 64 length?

Comment: Just use session cookies and modify the php.ini, specifically the hash function and the hash bits per character, http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function

Comment: imagine a GUID which is considered reasonably 'unique'ish then hash it using 'sha256'. base64_encode - store in the cookie. I suspect very hard to predict and is most likely 'unique enough' for your purposes? 'Over the top' - maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a suggestion to improve the token, instead of using the hex representation i would recommend to use base62 encoding. Such a string contains both upper and lower case characters and can therefore be shorter with the same information.

Next let's assume you create a random token with 20 base62 encoded characters, this would allow for 700'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000 combinations! Even if you can brute-force with [15 Giga SHA256/second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance), it would take about 7E17 years to find the correct token. Such a token with 20 characters requires only 15 bytes, so the 33 bytes you suggested in your first approach is surely more than enough.

I wrote a small [class](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#passwordreset) to help generating such base62 tokens, have a look at it if you are interested.

Comment: @RyanVincent - No base62 encoded strings contain 0-9 a-z A-Z, while base64 encoded strings also contain the + and = character, which can cause problems when used in an URL.

Comment: I am sorry - My bad! I have just learned some new information. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Should have mentioned it explicitely, no problem.

Comment: bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(30)) gives upper and lower case. why is base62 better?

Comment: @user2570937 - The `bin2hex` function converts every character to its hex representation (1 byte input -> 2 bytes output). The possible characters for the output are `0-9 a-f`, no other characters and no uppercase characters. Of course if a bigger alphabet can be used, you need less digits to represent the same value. An example: In our decimal system we kann write the value `8` with a single digit, in the binary system the same value is written like this `1000` and would need 4 digits.